# How to reduce the number of columns in a responsive layout?

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I'm trying to reduce the columns on a phone to two columns instead of the one it shows by default. There are several questions like this here and I tried using what they say the fixes are but none of them worked for me. I do use flex where those do not so maybe that is the problem?

```css
.wrapper {
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   padding:30px 20px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
} 


.box {
    border:1px solid red; 
    padding:0 20px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Text 1</div>
  <div class="box">Text 2</div>
  <div class="box">Text 3</div>
  <div class="box">Text 4</div>
  <div class="box">Text 5</div>
</div>
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/gubkj7cz/). The box class is just to illustrate the problem. If you resize the window, you will see the the boxes are all in one column. Would someone please explain how I make it stay at two columns?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its simple you can use media Query and Reduce the padding from left and right. 
e.g :

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
 .wrapper {
     padding:30px 10px;
    } 
 .box {padding:0 10px;}
}
```

I hope it helps you !! If you want to fix something else let me know I will do that.To learn about media Query you can follow this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Thanks !!

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't seem to work. I have update the https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/gubkj7cz/19/. If the window is resized, the boxes reduce to one column.

Comment: Thanks !! But you didn't add Media Query

Comment: And mobile screen width is 320px so on that it doesn't break into single column. Thanks !!

Comment: I may not be understanding your replies but the media command is there, in the updated jsfiddle. And if the window is resized, the columns reduce to one. Are you not seeing that?

Comment: Yes but it cames in one column at very small size ? But In mobile size it shows in 2 column. Have you get my point ?

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was trying to measure it in jsfiddle but couldn't so I created a new page here locally with just the code shown in the latest jsfiddle and when I reduce the window size down to the size of a phone it goes to one column. I used FF to measure the width and it was 320, which is larger than a regular phone.